# Unable to connect flutter with flask backend on local host

Tags: flutter, flask

I am trying to connect flutter to my flask backend. But flutter gives following error

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 50512
```

I even tried using my ipv4 address even localhost even host 0.0.0.0 and tried various ports but everytime the port keeps changing in flutter error. Sometimes like this

```
 Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 39223
```

Can anyone suggest how do I solve this. Here is my flask code

```
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=port) // changing to 0.0.0.0 also doesn't work neither different ports
```

I am able to connect to heroku server but not on localhost.

Comment: Are you trying it on flutter web or mobile?

Comment: I am using my mobile connecting thru usb cable

Comment: yes i have internet... I can connect to heroku server but Idk what's the issue with localhost

Comment: I get this when i run the app... Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:52173/sometexts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving 'localhost' as host in app.run() and port 5000. It will work on your real device. If using emulator then can use "10.0.2.2". Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: wow, that works like a charm.. Thank you so much. I was stuck for 3 days on this issue.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Get the local IPv4 address of your computer then run the flask app with the acquired IPv4 address (**flask run -h 192.168.X.X** )

in flutter app use this Ip

http.get('192.168.X.X:5000/api/user')